# Windows CE, Unicode and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, unicode, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I am trying to write a multi-language version of our existing Windows CE product range. I have a UTF8 (no BOM) encoded file and am trying to read it and display it in a MessageBox.

I am having some luck if I place Unicode characters in the CPP file and display it that way but some characters do not display.

I have tried UTF16, UTF16-LE and UTF16-BE files and none seems to be able to be displayed.

I have tried ifstream and wfstream and CFile - i have also tried a CStudioFile i found whilst googling. I can save the text back to another file and see it as Unicode - i just can't see it in my Windows CE application.

Note: I have compiled with Unicode character set switch on.

I am yet to work out what encoding the file is being read in - but as i stated I can save it back and read it as Unicode but not display in the dialog.

Any help\guidance appreciated to get the Unicode Text displayed in a MessageBox. Please note the C++ SDK for Windows CE is very cut down there are a lot of new features not available plus I have to compile it in Visual Studio 2008.

EDIT Code snippet from answer below. MessageBoxW does not display the correct text. It may just be a font issue on the emulator.

```
CFile file(L"c:\\test\\_utf8.txt", CFile::modeRead);
int filesize = file.GetLength();
CStringA strA;
file.Read(strA.GetBuffer(filesize), filesize);
strA.ReleaseBuffer();
CStringW strW = CA2W(strA, CP_UTF8);
strW.AppendChar(0);
MessageBoxW(0, strW, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Rather than making everyone GUESS what *could* be wrong with your code, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what your code is ACTALLY doing, then someone can tell you what you are doing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses `UTF16-LE`. Use `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, ...)` to convert `UTF8` to `UTF16-LE`, then display the `UTF16-LE` "wide char string" using Windows API functions.

In MFC you can use

```
CFile file(L"c:\\test\\_utf8.txt", CFile::modeRead);
int filesize = file.GetLength();
CStringA strA;
file.Read(strA.GetBuffer(filesize), filesize);
strA.ReleaseBuffer();
CStringW strW = CA2W(strA, CP_UTF8);
strW.AppendChar(0);
MessageBoxW(0, strW, 0, 0);
```

I am not sure what's available in WinCE. To use C++ standard library, open with `std::fstream`, read and convert `std::string` to `std::wstring`

Another example in plain API:

```
wchar_t* readfile(const wchar_t* filename)
{
    HANDLE handle = CreateFileW(filename, GENERIC_READ, 0, 
            NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return NULL;

    wchar_t *wbuf = NULL;
    int len = GetFileSize(handle, 0);
    if (len)
    {
        char *buf = new char[len];
        DWORD temp;
        ReadFile(handle, buf, len, &temp, 0);

        int wlen =
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, buf, len, 0, 0);
        wbuf = new wchar_t[wlen + 1];
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, buf, len, wbuf, wlen);
        wbuf[wlen] = 0;
        delete[]buf;
    }
    CloseHandle(handle);
    return wbuf;
}

...
wchar_t *wbuf = readfile(L"c:\\test\\utf8.txt");
if (wbuf) 
{
    MessageBoxW(0, wbuf, 0, 0);
    delete[]wbuf;
}
```

Comment: I only tried your first snippet of code and now I can see the string (in this test case) as Greek text in the debugger and in the output window. Just a side note I wasted a few hours tracking down a blank output string due to reading in the whole file. I restricted it to 200 characters and the OutputDebugString now works - i can see the text as Greek! Note I believe I am reading a UTF-8 file, though with your MFC code. The Message Box does not display the text in the emulator though - may be a font issue left to resolve.

Comment: I changed from MessageBox to trying to display in a control on a dialog and it works only after changing the resource font to "Arial Unicode MS". I suppose the answer is to now work out how to set the MessageBox font to "Arial Unicode MS".

Comment: So does the following code work in WinCE? `::MessageBoxW(0, L"ελληνική", 0, 0);`

Comment: The text you supplied does. The text I am trying does not "παρίσταταίε". The 'ί' comes out as a square box [] the rest is fine. I need to load the UTF-8 File into a database and then display messages in dialog and message boxes. Note the same text "παρίσταταίε" displays fine on a  button on a dialog with "Arial Unicode MS" font. The file I am playing with starts with "Οὐχὶ ταὐτὰ παρίσταταί μοι γιγνώσκειν, ὦ ἄνδρες".

Comment: I don't really know anything about Windows CE, you probably want to start another question about this issue. I would have thought WinCE uses a font like Tahoma. Another thing, start Notepad in Windows/Desktop, select the suspect font in Notepad and see if it is displayed correctly.